# anova() does not work properly with lme objects after updating - do I miss something?

Tags: r, anova, nlme, mgcv

I had a code that worked fine so far. I want to test things with `gls`, `lme` and `gamm` (from packages nlme and mgcv), and I compared different models with `anova()`. However, I needed another package, that did not work with my R version (which was almost one year old). Thus, I updated R (via the `updater` package) and RStudio.

The issue now is, that `anova()` does not give any output after running or only "Denom. DF: 91" and nothing else.

Now I tried different things and searched a lot, but I found no current threat dealing with such a problem, while looking at the help files just says, it should work that way I use it. Thus, I am suspecting that I miss something essential (probably even obvious), but I don't get it. I hope you can tell me where I do something wrong.

Here is some data to play with (copied from txt-file):

```
"treat" "x" "time" "nest"
"1" "1" 49.37 1 "K1"
"2" "1" 48.68 1 "K2"
"3" "2" 44.7 1 "T7"
"4" "2" 49.3 1 "T8"
"5" "1" 48.78 1 "K3"
"6" "2" 42.37 1 "T10"
"7" "1" 39.26 1 "K4"
"8" "2" 46.36 1 "T11"
"9" "1" 40.36 1 "K5"
"10" "2" 47.14 1 "T9"
"11" "1" 48.81 1 "K6"
"12" "1" 40.4 1 "K10"
"13" "2" 53.42 1 "T4"
"14" "2" 46.85 1 "T5"
"15" "2" 44.58 1 "T2"
"16" "2" 47.51 1 "T6"
"17" "1" 51.7 1 "K8"
"18" "1" 48.16 1 "K7"
"19" "2" 48.86 1 "T3"
"20" "1" 44.6 1 "K11"
"21" "1" 49.71 1 "K9"
"22" "2" 44.54 1 "T1"
"23" "2" 41.55 2 "T3"
"24" "1" 32.55 2 "K3"
"25" "1" 42.15 2 "K1"
"26" "2" 51.06 2 "T1"
"27" "1" 38.43 2 "K11"
"28" "2" 39.91 2 "T11"
"29" "1" 36.73 2 "K7"
"30" "2" 50.19 2 "T4"
"31" "1" 42.26 2 "K8"
"32" "1" 43.02 2 "K6"
"33" "2" 37.6 2 "T10"
"34" "1" 33.42 2 "K4"
"35" "2" 39.64 2 "T5"
"36" "2" 43.56 2 "T2"
"37" "2" 35.31 2 "T7"
"38" "2" 37 2 "T8"
"39" "2" 40.87 2 "T6"
"40" "1" 35.29 2 "K9"
"41" "2" 41.83 2 "T9"
"42" "1" 37.88 2 "K10"
"43" "1" 36.5 2 "K5"
"44" "1" 34.21 3 "K4"
"45" "1" 38.04 3 "K6"
"46" "1" 35.14 3 "K3"
"47" "2" 38.18 3 "T10"
"48" "1" 40.26 3 "K11"
"49" "2" 37.09 3 "T3"
"50" "2" 43.1 3 "T11"
"51" "2" 34.26 3 "T7"
"52" "1" 36.58 3 "K9"
"53" "1" 35.81 3 "K2"
"54" "1" 39.83 3 "K10"
"55" "2" 37.65 3 "T6"
"56" "1" 39.8 3 "K7"
"57" "1" 36.41 3 "K8"
"58" "1" 35.22 3 "K5"
"59" "2" 39.68 3 "T8"
"60" "2" 41.12 3 "T1"
"61" "2" 36.93 3 "T9"
"62" "1" 35.66 3 "K1"
"63" "2" 36.91 3 "T4"
"64" "2" 38.84 3 "T5"
"65" "2" 34.31 3 "T2"
"66" "1" 32.71 4 "K9"
"67" "2" 37.84 4 "T11"
"68" "1" 28.01 4 "K10"
"69" "2" 39.69 5 "T11"
"70" "2" 35.08 4 "T10"
"71" "2" 34.43 4 "T9"
"72" "1" 32.12 4 "T8"
"73" "2" 30.41 4 "T7"
"74" "1" 31.81 4 "K7"
"75" "2" 36.41 4 "T6"
"76" "1" 29.17 5 "K6"
"77" "1" 28.59 4 "K6"
"78" "2" 33.99 4 "T5"
"79" "1" 30.41 4 "K5"
"80" "1" 29.8 4 "K4"
"81" "2" 34.72 4 "T4"
"82" "2" 34.38 4 "T3"
"83" "1" 28.12 4 "K3"
"84" "2" 34.62 4 "T2"
"85" "1" 31.88 4 "K2"
"86" "1" 29.35 4 "K1"
"87" "2" 37.95 4 "T1"
"88" "2" 40.85 5 "T4"
"89" "2" 35.07 5 "T5"
"90" "2" 36.15 5 "T8"
"91" "2" 36.48 5 "T10"
"92" "1" 33.73 4 "K8"
"93" "1" 28.17 5 "K9"
"94" "1" 32.81 5 "K10"
"95" "1" 32.17 4 "K11"
```

And this is basically one of the models I try to run:

```
test <- read.table(file="C:/Users/marvi_000/Desktop/testdata.txt")
str(test)
test$treat <- as.factor(test$treat)
test$nest <- as.factor(test$nest)

library(nlme)

m.test <- gls(x ~ treat * time,
                 correlation = corAR1(form =~ time | nest),
                 test, na.action = na.omit)
anova(m.test)
```

the output is:

> Denom. DF: 91

When comparing models with a`nova(m1, m2)` nothing happens at all.

The same is true when I run a `gamm` from package `mgcv` and using `anova(m$lme)` or `anova(m1$lme, m2$lme)`.

I would appreciate any help or hint, pointing me towards the right direction. Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
After some discussion, I found out, that it is a problem with the scripts. I'm using RStudio and RMarkdown. However, when I run the code (with cntrl+enter, line by line) within the markdown script, the `anova(lmemodel)` command does not work as supposed to. However, if I just copy this single command into a plane r script (still using the current environment), the command is executed properly showing the desired output.
I have no clue what is happening there. If anybody has an idea where the problem is, or how to solve it, I would still be happy to hear it.

Comment: which R version are you on? Unfortunately I am on R 3.6.1 and it works ok. I think it's something wrong with your nlme package..

Comment: Now its 4.0.3. 3.6.1 was my previous version where it worked too.
I also tried to delete and reinstall the package. No success though.

Comment: ok i tested with 4.0.3, and nlme_3.1-151, it works

Comment: hm... It's the same I have... what's going on there? This rather seems stupid...

Comment: Did you use a clean installation or via updater? Maybe I should remove all my r stuff and reinstall everything from scratch... hmm...

Comment: Ok, this becoming even weirder.... I'm using RStudio and RMarkdown. When I move the code within a clean r script the code runs normal. Even when I use the markdown script making the real model with my real data but running the anova(m) command in the clean skript (without cleaning the environment) it also works.
It seems there is somehow a problem between markdown script execution and the command?!? I have no clue...
Edit: of course I just use cntrl+enter to run the code line by line, not the markdown functionality

Comment: not very sure.. i can't see the markdown.. so unless the markdown calls a specific package... or you have more than 1 R version installed.. this should not happen

Comment: I always thought, that markdown just calls the code as base r does. But it looks like there is something in between. Maybe it is a bug...
However, I can work with this 'workaround' for the first instance. But maybe someone else has an idea what happens there and how to fix it.
Thanks for your effort @StupidWolf!

Comment: Have you tried to add `results = "asis" ` to your R chunk? `{r results = "asis"} `

Comment: @ViviG this does not work either, which is probably not surprising as the problem arises when I just execude the code line by line (cntrl+enter), where I think, the tags of the markdown script are not considered. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Is your file .Rmd or .Rmarkdown? If it is .Rmarkdown, you could try to do the same in a .Rmd document instead. The two file types do behave differently.

Comment: This did not help. However, I set up a completely new R installation with everything (RStudio and all packages etc.) after deleting everything first.
Now it seems to work. At least I did not face this issue again. Maybe there was something corrupted while updating the last time.